# WPF capture the content of a Label that is being populated with a Binding XPath

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I am simply trying to grab the content of a Label and place it into a variable.
Here is my Window.xaml

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}">Study:</Label>
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Name="Study_Name_Ref"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and here is my Window.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using APPIL_Importer.Methods;
using APPIL_Importer.DicomMethods;

namespace APPIL_Importer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StudyImporter.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StudyImporter : Window
    {
        ConsoleOutputStream outputter;
        public StudyImporter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

            outputter = new ConsoleOutputStream(TestBox);
            Console.SetOut(outputter);

        }

        public StudyImporter(object data) : this()
        {
            this.DataContext = data;
            this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        }

        private void Confirm_Import_On_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("This will import every series in the Import Directory. Are you sure you want to Import?", "Import Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            string study_name_container = Study_Name_Ref.Content.ToString();

            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome Dave. Would you like to play a game?");
                    MessageBox.Show(study_name_container);
                    //ModifyDicom.ModifyCommonDicomTags(path_to_file);
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    MessageBox.Show("CANCEL", "Nope!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to capture the content of the Label named "Study_Name_Ref" but what I get is the following:
System.Xml.XmlAttribute

any suggestions?

Comment: How does your static resource "studyTitle" looks like can, you add it to your question? (also this link might be useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-xml-data-using-an-xmldataprovider-and-xpath-queries)

Comment: "studyTitle" is just the styles provided to the label that are in the App.xaml file. It doesn't have anything to do with the data.

Comment: :-) you right of course, i read your code a bit too quick, didn't notice it was style binding.

Comment: Hi, i see that no one answered yet, i guess that it might be due to the fact that your question missing the part of binding the XmlDataProvider that is used with XPath=@Name. Also what do you see in the label?

Comment: After watch a bunch of coding structure/architecture videos. I decided to follow the MVVM pattern with my WPF application, after restructuring the code it made it a lot easier to achieve what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label can received object as Content.

Apparently in your case the label received an instance of System.Xml.XmlAttribute

Then maybe you can try

```
XmlAttribute attr = Study_Name_Ref.Content as XmlAttribute;

if(attr != null)
{
   string study_name_container = attr.Value;
}
```